# How can I get git's `.git` path from git itself?

Tags: bash, git

I am trying to write a shell script that needs to be able to find the `.git` folder for the current directory, correctly handling all of the following possibilities:

- I might be in a bare repo, in which case the `.git` folder is either `.` or `..` or `../..` or so on.
- I might be in a submodule (in which I'll find a `.git` *file* that contains the path to the git folder)
- `$GIT_DIR` might be set.
- I might not be in a git repo at all

I have this:

```
seemsToBeGitdir() {
    # Nothing special about "config --local -l" here, it's just a git
    # command that errors out if the `--git-dir` argument is wrong.
    git --git-dir "$1" config --local -l >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
    return $?
}

gitdir() {
    local cursor relpath
    if [ "$GIT_DIR" ]; then
        echo "$GIT_DIR"
        return 0
    fi
    cursor="$(pwd)"
    while [ -e "$cursor" ] && ! seemsToBeGitdir "$cursor"; do
        # Git won't traverse mountpoints looking for .git
        if mountpoint -q "$cursor"; then
            return 1
        fi

        # We might be in a submodule
        if [ -f "$cursor/.git" ]; then
            # If .git is a file, its syntax is "gitdir: " followed by a
            # relative path.
            relpath="$(awk '/^gitdir:/{print$2}' "$cursor/.git")"
            # convert the relative path to an absolute path.
            cursor="$(readlink -f "$cursor/$relpath")"
            continue
        fi

        if seemsToBeGitdir "$cursor/.git"; then
            echo "$cursor/.git"
            return 0
        fi

        cursor="$(dirname "$cursor")"
    done
    echo "$cursor"
}
```

And it works, but seems way too complicated -- clearly, git itself does this sort of calculation every time it's invoked. Is there a way to make git itself tell me where `.git` is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `git rev-parse`, which has options specifically for this:

```
git rev-parse --git-dir
```

See also:

```
git rev-parse --absolute-git-dir
```

(new in Git version 2.13.0), and:

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

and:

```
git rev-parse --show-cdup
```

(note that its output is empty if you are already in the top level of the repository).  View your own documentation to find out which options your Git supports; most of these have been around since Git 1.7, though.

Comment: The specific form I needed was `git rev-parse --absolute-git-dir 2>/dev/null`. For posterity, these options are [documented on the rev-parse manpage](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#git-rev-parse---absolute-git-dir) and I am apparently bad at searching the internet.